# Difference between @SpringQueryMap and @QueryMap

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

Difference between @SpringQueryMap(package org.springframework.cloud.openfeign;) and @QueryMap(package feign)  in FeignClient.

For Example, I can use @SpringQueryMap with Pageable in FeignClient method, but I cant use @QueryMap

```
@PostMapping("/user/getUserList")
ResponseEntity<Page<UserDto>> getUserList(@RequestBody UserSearchDto searchInputDto, @SpringQueryMap Pageable page);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated in the Spring documentation, difference between `@QueryMap` and `@SpringQueryMap` is that:

> the default OpenFeign QueryMap annotation is incompatible with Spring because it lacks a value property.

[Spring Cloud documentation. Feign part](https://the%20default%20OpenFeign%20QueryMap%20annotation%20is%20incompatible%20with%20Spring%20because%20it%20lacks%20a%20value%20property.)

So instead of `@QueryMap`, in Spring Feign Client  `@SpringQueryMap` should be used to annotate a POJO or Map parameter as a query parameter map.